# Raspberry pi cam picture scaling and offset problems

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a question on the Raspberry Pi cam. I am using openCV on a raspberry Pi 2 to make a line-follower for a robot.

Basically the idea is to find the direction of a line in the image using derivatives and color segmentation.

However, I'm found some strange behaviour when I compare the results on an ordinary PC webcamera and the picam. The algorithm works well on the PC webcam, and the direction indicator sits spot on the line. On the picam there is a strange scale and offset which I don't understand.

On both platforms I have tried both the `cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH/HEIGHT)` to rescale the image, as well as the `resize` function.  Both of them still produce the strange offset. I use the `circle(...)` and `line(...)` methods in openCV to overlay the line and circles on the captured image.

Could anyone help to explain this behaviour? See the links below for a visual caption.

[picam](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25182448/20150602_093756.jpg)
[webcam](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25182448/20150602_094239.jpg)

Regards

Comment: Can you add some of your code? I also suggest you to directly add the pics (with a screenshot if you can) in the question (links can be broken after a while).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add the pictures directly because of the policies of Stackexchange, so had to provide links instead.

I eventually discovered the solution to the problem, and it involved changing the order of the taps of a derivative filter for the Windows and Linux versions of the program. Exactely why this is the case is a mystery to me, and may involve differences in compiler optimization (Visual Studio 13 vs g++ 4.6.3), or maybe a silly error on my part.

On the the PC I use {1 0 -1} filter taps, on the RP2 I have to use {-1 0 1} instead.

The filter runs on a S8 (-127..127) image, so there is no issue of a wraparound.

At any rate, I consider the issue closed.